# Function with type a -> b in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, unification

Is there any kind of function in Haskell that has type `a -> b`? That means, is it possible to write a function such that `f :: a -> b`? I don't think a function like that exists for the following reason: suppose that we found f where `f :: a -> b`, what would `f 2` produce? a value of type `b`, but what is `b` since Haskell cannot infere (I think) it from the arguments I gave? Is this correct? Otherwise, can you give me an example of such a function?

Comment: You are right that it is hard to write an interesting function of that type; but the _reason_ you gave is incorrect. It is certainly allowed to write functions which result in ambiguous types when applied in certain ways.

Comment: Any type that’s not a tautology when interpreted as a logical formula is the type of a partial function, which must throw an error or loop forever, at least for some inputs. `forall a b. a -> b` isn’t a tautology, as you can easily think of counterexamples: `Int -> Void` for example—just because you gave me an `Int` doesn’t mean I can give you a `Void`! Same goes for `head :: [a] -> a`. You can tell just by looking at the type that it can’t return a result if you give it an empty list `[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Barring ⊥ (*bottom value* – `undefined` etc.), which is always possible but never useful, there can indeed be no such function. This is one of the simplest instances of the so-called [free theorems](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=99370.99404) that we get from polymorphic type signatures.

You're on the right track with your intuitive explanation of why this is not possible, though it went off in the end. Yes, you can consider `f (5 :: Int)`. The problem is *not* that the compiler “can't infer” what `b` would be – that would be the case for many realistic functions, e.g.

```
fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b
```

makes perfect sense; `b` will be inferred *from the environment* in which `fromIntegral x` is used. For instance, I might write<sup>†</sup>

```
average :: [Double] -> Double
average l = sum l / fromIntegral (length l)
```

In this case, `length l :: a` has the fixed type `Int` and `fromIntegral (length l) :: b` must have the fixed type `Double` to fit in the environment, and unlike in most other languages with type inference, information from the environment is available hereto in a Hindley-Milner based language.

No, the problem with `f :: a -> b` is that you could instantiate `a` and `b` to *any* ridiculous combination of types, not just different number types. Because `f` is unconstrainedly polymorphic, it would have to be able to convert *any type into any other type*.

In particular, it would be able to convert into the *vacuous type* [`Void`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Void.html#t:Void).

```
evil :: Int -> Void
evil = f
```

And then I could have

```
muahar :: Void
muahar = f 0
```

But, by construction of `Void`, there *cannot* be a value of this type (save for ⊥ which you can't evaluate without either crashing or looping infinitely).

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>It should be noted that this is by some standards not a very good way of computing the average.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

In order to implement `f :: a -> b`, it means that `f` has to be able to return *any possible type*. Even types that don't exist today, but somebody could define in ten years' time. Without some kind of reflection feature, that's obviously impossible.

Well... "impossible" is a big word... As the other answers point out, it's impossible *excluding bottom*. In other words, `f` can never *return* a value of type `b`. It *can* throw an exception, or loop forever. But (arguably) neither of those things is really "returning a value".

```
f1 :: a -> b
f1 = error "f1"

f2 :: a -> b
f2 s = error "f2"

f3 :: a -> b
f3 x = f3 x
```

These functions are all subtly different, and they all compile just fine. And, of course, *they're all useless!* So yes, there is no *useful* function with type `a -> b`.

If you want to split hairs:

- `f1` throws an exception.
- `f1 'x'` throws an exception.
- `f2` is a normal-looking function.
- `f2 'x'` throws an exception.
- `f3` is a normal-looking function.
- `f3 'x'` doesn't throw an exception, but it loops forever, so it never actually *returns* anything.

Basically any function you see that returns "any type" is a function that never actually returns. We can see this in unusual monads. For example:

```
f4 :: a -> Maybe b
```

It is *perfectly possible* to implement this function without throwing an exception or looping forever.

```
f4 x = Nothing
```

Again, we're not actually *returning* a `b`. We could similarly do

```
f5 :: a -> [b]
f5 x = []

f6 :: a -> Either String b
f6 x = Left "Not here"

f7 :: a -> Parser b
f7 x = fail "Not here"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is, I think, exactly one, but it is cheating a little bit:

```
> let f _ = undefined
> :t f
f:: t -> t1
```

This only exists because bottom is considered a value of every type.

Comment: I don't think it's cheating at all. If you're going to return a value of an unknown/unspecified type, I can't think of any other value you could possibly return except bottom.

Comment: "Exactly one" is probably a bit strong. If you mean semantically, then there are other options like `f = undefined` and `f x = seq x undefined` that are not really different in a practical way, and if you mean practically, then there are other options like `f x = f x` (i.e. that loop instead of throwing an exception) that are not really different in a semantic way. And of course there's the obvious caveat, which lives in a strange space both semantically and practically...

Comment: @DanielWagner Would it be fair to say exactly one *pure* function?

Comment: @chepner What makes `f = undefined` or `f x = f x` less pure than `f _ = undefined`?

Comment: I meant for `f x = seq x undefined`; looking only at the input and output, that's the same as `f x = undefined`. As for `f = undefined`, isn't that the same as `f _ = undefined` if you assume that `f :: a -> b`? (The only difference being in the former you have `undefined :: a -> b` and in the latter `undefined :: b`.) I don't really understand the exact semantics of `undefined` well enough to say if `f x = f x` is the same as or different from `f _ = undefined`.

Comment: @chepner Semantically, `f = undefined` and `f _ = undefined` are different: one is bottom and the other is not. But you are right to point out that `f _ = undefined` and `f x = seq x undefined` are semantically the same.

Comment: I think I was getting carried away with `undefined :: a`, assuming that you could think of `a` as being a function type as well, then applying that "function" to another value.

Comment: @chepner Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

> ... but what is `b` since Haskell cannot infer it from the arguments I gave?

Depending on the context, Haskell can infer the return type; say:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Cast a b where
    cast :: a -> b

instance Cast a a where
    cast = id

instance Cast Int String where
    cast = show

instance Cast Int Double where
    cast = fromIntegral
```

then,

```
cast :: Cast a b => a -> b
```

and if given enough context, Haskell knows which function to use:

```
\> let a = 42 :: Int
\> let b = 100.0 :: Double

\> "string: " ++ cast a  -- Int -> String
"string: 42"

\> b * cast a            -- Int -> Double
4200.0
```

Comment: Adding a type constraint changes the problem, though, in the same way asking how many functions have type `a -> a` depends on whether or not there are constraints. For example, `id` is the only function of type `a -> a`, but there are lots of functions of type `Num a => a -> a`.