# Function input-output template type

Tags: typescript

I have seen the following valid template function type defined like this:

```
type func = <I, O>(data: I) => O;
```

I understand this template is somehow for generic input and output types, but I cannot figure out how it can actually be used...

Any examples? I couldn't come up with a declaration that would match such a template. Or is it not a template at all? I am confused here as to the syntax.

Comment: The term "template" isn't really used in TypeScript (or maybe any language with type erasure).  In C++ it is literally a template in that the compiler creates real code for each use of it, whereas in Java or TypeScript nothing is being copied anywhere.

Comment: @jcalz not sure how this helps us here.

Comment: It's just a terminology comment.  I'm writing an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you saw that type being used, but it is a *concrete* type representing a [*generic* function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

```
type Funky = <I, O>(data: I) => O;
```

If you had a function of type `Funky`, you could call it on absolutely any single argument of any type you want (as `I` is not [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints)), and it could produce an output of any type you want (`O` is not constrained either).

As you noticed, it's difficult to imagine such a function.  In a more soundly-typed language like Haskell, it would be [impossible to implement that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470354/function-with-type-a-b-in-haskell) without some [evil magic](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html).  TypeScript lets you [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) just about anything, so you could write an implementation with no compiler warnings, but it would still be a very unsafe function:

```
const unsafeCoerce: Funky = (x: any) => x; // any is an escape-hatch from the type system
```

Here, `unsafeCoerce` just returns its input, meaning that it supposedly allows the caller to coerce its input to any type you want, even if that is a lie:

```
const threeAsString: string = unsafeCoerce(3); // DANGER 
// const unsafeCoerce: <number, string>(data: number) => string

threeAsString.charAt(0); // no error at compile time, TypeError at runtime
```

So I don't see much use for that function either.

---

A similar looking type with a *very different meaning* is:

```
type Func<I, O> = (data: I) => O;
```

This is a *generic* type representing a *concrete* function (or, a family of concrete functions).  You can't have a function of type `Func`, because it hasn't specified its generic parameters:

```
const nope: Func = (x: any) => x; // error! 
//          ~~~~ <-- Generic type 'Func' requires 2 type argument(s).
```

Instead, you would need to specify the parameters, which becomes a function from some specific input type to some specific output type, which are much easier to come by:

```
const stringLength: Func<string, number> = x => x.length; // okay
```

If all you were doing was plugging in concrete values for `I` and `O` when declaring a function, there wouldn't be much point in doing this.  But there are reasons why you might want to use a generic type like `Func<I, O>`, most obviously in higher-order typed data types.

For example, if you wanted to make a higher-order function `apply(f, x)` which takes a function `f` and a parameter `x` and returns `f(x)`, you find yourself wanting to use a type like `Func`:

```
function apply<I, O>(f: Func<I, O>, x: I): O {
  return f(x); // okay
}
const out = apply((x: number) => x.toLocaleString(), 123); // string
```

---

It's *possible* that you saw something like `Func<I, O>` and remembered it like `Funky`.  Or *maybe* someone is *actually* using a `Funky` type like that, for some nefarious purpose that only they know (unless you look at what it's doing or link it in your question).

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwNYigXigHgJIBooDyAfABQAmAhsBQFxTYCU6RhA3AFDsDGA9ggM7AoifhQBmEAMI8IAJy4Q68ZKgwkAHnQoIQTNC3WsoAemNRtqAJb9zCKBH5cKkALQALKlzdQxsngFsoYDdoUEgofhBBCH9OXgEhYNkICABBfgBlYFlLBABzOkEc-PRhAXEpGXkIEgBmBg5TKHjBMtEJaTkFOkwEOH8AIzl8Ity80kpqOj7BuT0WUfzOJJT0rOK8gDovCllU4BIABgaTMwQee1k-WXMhXn8wSwAbUMt-CHxZRGA36AAVcAQACiVx4sk4TRcUOhMNhcPh0NOy0BsEQXBw+GIpXIVFo9HmbDifFa50gSjR2M0tl0zCghlOl2uAEJ2E0oOyORyAH48rlYKFQADiEAQcksXCCKIA5MouFKoMkAI5wSzJGwAJkl4V2eX6IoO-AYmyJCQi2TGABkRXlguSEOjFnl8DMhrIWBh1LT1JsXvlgkYmjwkBQQJwxGifnxzGAwE8QBjCKQxHb0XhE-gqYw6AQoABvdjs5LAOCyOxiDQNdgAXxNrR4cCEGGcsZAJA0036roJ3uAPAtPCcL3WYxIDHwAEZ1fUA2ZHewgA)